# Track delivery status of DHL via form

Tags: php, tracking, dhl

I have a question. I have the following PHP script

```
<?php
$dhlsendnumber=$_GET['dhlsendnumber'];
{
   $uri="https://www.dhl.de/de/privatkunden/dhl-sendungsverfolgung.html?piececode=$dhlsendenummer";
   
   header("location: $uri");
   
   Exit;
}
?>
```

This allows me to check the status of a delivery number from DHL using a form with the following PHP.

```
    <?php
// basic form saved under the name: dhlsendeverfolgung.php
?>

<form action="dhlsendeverfolgung.php" method="get">

<p>Enter your DHL shipment number<br>.
<input type="Text" name="dhlsendenummer"></p>

<input type="Submit" name="" value="Request shipment status of your DHL package">

</form>
```

Maybe there is a better way to do this, but this works so far.

But this only works if I put the dhlsendeverfolgung.php in the root directory.

But I would like to be able to track a delivery number from a subpage of my website like https://samplepage/dhl-tracken using the form with the above code. But I don't know in which folder I have to put the php file to achieve this or whatelse I have to do so that the link is found like when I have the form on the home page and in the root the php file.

Can someone help me to achieve this?

Furthermore, I would like to achieve that the DHL web page with the query opens in a new window and does not open in the same,

What do I need to do?

Would appreciate help

Comment: In the action, just specify the path to where you're placing your PHP script. For example `<form action="dhl-tracken/dhlsendeverfolgung.php" method="get">`. (assuming the form is in the root dir, and the script is in dhl-tracken.  In the event your "path" doesn't exist, just create the directory `dhl-tracken` in the root dir.  Note, if you put the form _and_ the script in dhl-tracken, you don't need to specify the path in your action, just the script as you have it currently.

Comment: I tried your solution, but unfortunately I am still new and could not implement your solution.Therefore my questions about it.

I have the form in the page samplepage.com/my-package-trace.
There I have added the code from you, so that there is now from you:
<form action="dhl-tracken/dhlsendeverfolgung.php" method="get">

I have my php file (dhlsendeverfolgung.php) under httpdocs.
It still comes up with the following result:
samplepage.com/my-packet-tracking/dhlsend-tracking.php?dhlsend-number=00340434326059XXXXX
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could actually simplify this alot and do away with the other page entirely using javascript:

```js
function sendToDHL(form) {
  let num = form.querySelector('input[name="dhlsendenummer"]').value.trim();
  if (!num) {
    alert("Please input a tracking number");
    return;
  }
  let url = "https://www.dhl.de/de/privatkunden/dhl-sendungsverfolgung.html?piececode=" + num;
  window.open(url, 'DHLTracking');
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="sendToDHL(this); return false;">
  <p>Enter your DHL shipment number.<br>
    <input type="text" name="dhlsendenummer"></p>
  <input type="submit" name="" value="Request shipment status of your DHL package">
</form>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding and your suggestion. I have added the form code on the page so this good. But in which folder do I have to add the js-file with your code with the function. I tried to add it as dhl-tracken.js in different folders but I could not get it work in connection with the form on my page https://samplepage.com/my-parcel-tracking.

Comment: you can put the .js file anywhere. You can put it at the top level of your website, right next to index.php and then `<script src="/dhl-tracken.js"></script>`

Comment: Thanks, for your suggestion and help. This works. I added the script to my header and now it works.

Comment: Appreciate your help, Bjoern